# C++ SHFileOperation 64bit OS

Tags: c, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

This old C++ functions works on 32bit OS, but not on a 64bit OS.
I want to Copy a Folder.
Do you know what I have to change?

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at WindowsApplication1.FolderCopy.SHFileOperation(SHFILEOPSTRUCT& lpFileOp)
   at WindowsApplication1.FolderCopy.CopyFolder(String strSource, String strTarget)
   at WindowsApplication1.Form1.Restore()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

This is the function:

```vb
    'Declaration of the API
    Private Declare Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
         "SHFileOperationA" (ByRef lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As Integer
#End Region

Public Shared Function CopyFolder(ByVal strSource As String, ByVal strTarget As String) As Boolean
    Dim _ShFile As New SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    Dim lngUsedFlags As Long
    lngUsedFlags = lngUsedFlags Or FO_Func.FOF_NOCONFIRMATION
    lngUsedFlags = lngUsedFlags Or FO_Func.FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR
    lngUsedFlags = lngUsedFlags Or FO_Func.FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS
    lngUsedFlags = lngUsedFlags Or FO_Func.FOF_NOERRORUI

    _ShFile.wFunc = FO_Func.FO_COPY
    _ShFile.fFlags = lngUsedFlags
    _ShFile.pFrom = strSource & vbNullChar
    _ShFile.pTo = strTarget & vbNullChar
    If SHFileOperation(_ShFile) = 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? If anything it should be tagged C since `SHFileOperation` is a C function. But that doesn't matter, you're programming in Visual Basic, so that is the language tag you should use.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `SHFILEOPSTRUCT` on the VB side? Most likely some of the types are being marshaled incorrectly.

Comment: Use the pinvoke from pinvoke.net including the struct.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis here is my declaration: 'Private Structure SHFILEOPSTRUCT
        Dim hwnd As Integer
        Dim wFunc As Integer
        Dim pFrom As String
        Dim pTo As String
        Dim fFlags As Short
        Dim fAnyOperationsAborted As Boolean
        Dim hNameMappings As Integer
        Dim lpszProgressTitle As String
    End Structure'

Comment: Your declaration is wrong, won't work in 64-bit mode.  hwnd and hNameMappings are IntPtr.  Just don't do this, it is already wrapped [by the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Don't ask in comments. Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is with the `hNameMappings` field. The C declaration of that field is `LPVOID hNameMappings` which could be 4 or 8 bytes depending on the architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit). I think you need to use `IntPtr` type for that field since `IntPtr` will be 4 bytes in 32-bits and 8 in 64-bits. However I'm unsure what happens with the string fields, since those pointers also do grow in the case of 64-bits. But you could start and check if using `IntPtr` for the `hNameMappings` field does the trick.